# Wordpress page connected to custom mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm using wordpress as a base for my website, I created a custom (not wp default) MySQL table with 3 columns in which I want to store simple informations such as Names, Birthdays and Email contacts. However I also want to create a page in my wordpress site that can connect to this specific database where I can compile a form and by pressing a button update this database. Is there an easy way to do so or should I just made a .php file and not using wordpress?

Comment: please see something similar here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162614/how-to-make-connection-to-wordpress-data-base-in-a-plugin. I believe you need to write some PHP code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to Database with mysqli, mysqli\_connect, or PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512625/cannot-connect-to-database-with-mysqli-mysqli-connect-or-pdo)